# Migrate boot partition on encrypted install

Tags: boot, manjaro

I installed Manjaro with full disk encryption using the option in Manjaro setup. When I boot, a grub prompt asks me for a password, after which I get a grub menu.

I want to change this behavior, so that the grub menu comes up before unlocking, and only asks for passphrase if I end up choosing to boot into Manjaro. What are tge steps to do this?

Comment: Full disk encryption also encrypts the areas of the disk used by grub. So they need to be unlocked before grub can post the menu. As for changing it, I am not sure as to how.